# How to select certain indices from a list? (i.e. the 1st, 6th and 13th value)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop

I have an enumerate for loop inside another enumerate loop and I want to use certain items from the inner list. I thought the following:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'],['one','two','three','four','five'],['1','2','3','4','5']

for number, list in enumerate(list1):
    for num, item in enumerate(list[0, 1, 4]):
    print item
```

would print out:

```
a
b
e
one
two
five
1
2
5
```

But instead I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. I know I can select a range using `list1[0:5]` for example so I assumed I could explicitly select items as well.

Can anyone explain how to achieve this print out?

Comment: For me, your question is not clear. The title is different from the content. Also, are you sure you did not make a typo in `list1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the indexes you want, you simply need to index said list at the specific indexes, and print the values.

You should also note however, that list are *zero indexed*. The first value is at index `0`. That means you want 0, 1, 4, and not 1, 2, 5

```
>>> list1 = [['a','b','c','d','e'],['one','two','three','four','five'],['1','2','3','4','5']]
>>> 
>>> for lst in list1:
        a, b, c = lst[0], lst[1], lst[4]
        print a
        print b
        print c


a
b
e
one
two
five
1
2
5
>>>
```

If you need a more general solution, you can iterate over the indexes you want to access, and print them out:

```
>>> def print_elements_at_indexs(indexes, lst):
    for sublst in lst:
        for index in indexes:
            print(sublst[index])


>>> print_elements_at_indexs([0, 1, 4], list1)
a
b
e
one
two
five
1
2
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the second loop:

```
for num, item in enumerate(list[0, 1, 4]):
```

What you have written - `list[1, 2, 5]` was wrong in two accounts - `list()` is a reserved keyword you reassigned in the previous loop (not critical, but you shouldn't do it, period :), and you are passing a wrong slice construct - this is not the syntax how to select these 3 members. Plus, the indices are 0 based - the 1st element is 0, and so on.

Here's revised code based on your approach:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'],['one','two','three','four','five'],['1','2','3','4','5']

for sub_list in list1:
    for num in (0, 1, 4):
        print sub_list[num]
```

No need to use `enumerate()`, as you're not using its index anyways.

Comment: Yes you are correct it is a method, but I named my list `list1` not `list`. I have fixed up the indices ordering. However I am now getting the error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` when I place my list items inside parenthesis like above

Comment: I've realized a crucial mistake in my initial understanding of your code (you were reassigning `list` to a local variaboe), and have edited my answer. The final loop is actually the "longer" version of the list comprehansion answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> list1 = [['a','b','c','d','e'],['one','two','three','four','five'],['1','2','3','4','5']]
>>> index1 = [1,2,5]
>>> [j for i in list1 for index,j in enumerate(i) if index+1 in index1]
['a', 'b', 'e', 'one', 'two', 'five', '1', '2', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
[v for _list in list1 for i,v in enumerate(_list) if i in [0,1,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [['a','b','c','d','e'],['one','two','three','four','five'],['1','2','3','4','5']]

for number, lst in enumerate(list1):
    for num, item in enumerate(lst):
        if num in [0,1,4]:
            print item
```

Note : try avoiding built-in keyword as variable in your program.